# class with friend rather than forward declaration,: which compiler is correct

Tags: c++, gcc, cl

I have this simple C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct obj {
  friend int f(int);

  void m(int x) { std::cout << "f(" << x << ") = " << f(x) << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  obj o;
  o.m(21);
}


int f(int x) {
  return 2*x;
}
```

If I compile with the GNU C++ compiler `g++`, I get the error *prog.cpp:7:55: error: 'f' was not declared in this scope*

However, if I compile it with `cl` (and `/W4`) it compiles and executes fine.

I am not sure which compiler is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From cppreference on [friend declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend):

> A name first declared in a friend declaration within class or class template X becomes a member of the innermost enclosing namespace of X, but is not visible for lookup (except argument-dependent lookup that considers X) unless a matching declaration at the namespace scope is provided

A matching declaration at global scope is provided, but only *after* the definition of `obj::m()`. I think it's correct to refuse the call to `f` at this point. You can see the effect e.g. this compiles with both `gcc` and `clang`,

```
int f(int);

class obj { /* as before... */ };
```

and so does this:

```
struct obj {
  friend int f(int);

  void m(int x); 
};

int f(int);

void obj::m(int x) { std::cout << "f(" << x << ") = " << f(x) << std::endl; }
```

Comment: Or `friend int f(obj const&, int);` so ADL would have worked by adding that first parameter (even if it is a dummy parameter).